# Sending Checkbox Values to PHP page using javascript Ajax and not jQuery

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax

I have a situation in which i need to do insert queries for every check box selected through an ajax request sent to a php script which would do the insert in mysql.

i know how to do it without an ajax call via the simple form submission with a variable like groups[] as an array and running the foreach loop in php for every value in the array.

How do i send the array a via post ajax request?

a sample code:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='groups[]' value='1'>Group A
<input type='checkbox' name='groups[]' value='2'>Group B
<input type='checkbox' name='groups[]' value='3'>Group C
```

Please help, i know this might be easy but i am just not getting it. and guys, please don't give any example of jquery or the likes as i want pure html, javascript and php solution.

Thanks community...

Here's the Javascript function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addResp(tid){

a = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('course_add_resp').value);
b = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('term_add_resp').value);
c = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('paper_add_resp').value);

var elements = document.getElementsByName('groups[]');  
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
if (elements[i].checked){
    data.push('groups[]='+elements[i].value);
   }
}
params = "tid="+tid+"&course="+a+"&sem="+b+"&paper="+c+"&grp="+data;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
   {
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('respBackground'));
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('respBox'));      
contents = xmlhttp.responseText;    
if(contents == "done"){
window.location = "teachers.php";
} else{
document.getElementById("studentBox").innerHTML = "There was a problem serving the     request.";
 }

    }
  }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","assignresp.php",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send(params);

 }

</script>
```

and the php script:

```
  <?php

  $tid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tid']);
  $cid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']);
  $sem = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sem']);
  $paper = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['paper']);
  $session = 12;
  $type = 1;

  $groups = $_POST['grp'];

  foreach ($groups as $value ) {
      $q1 = "insert into iars(sessionid,teacherid,courseid,semester,paperid,groupid,type)    values('$session','$tid','$cid','$sem','$paper','$value','$type')";
      $r1 = mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());
      if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
          echo "done";
      }
      else{
          echo "fail"; 
      } 
  }


 ?>
```

Comment: you will have to write a lot more code it you want to spurn jquerry.

Comment: i don't want to use jqeury here...

Comment: and i'm sure you have a good reason ...

Comment: i have never used it and always have tried to write my own javascript with some help from the community.. its gonna take a while to understand that too for which i am a little short on time...

Comment: its become practically the standard and there are more ajax tutorials using it than not, so it should actully save time.

Comment: try this tutorial: `http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/`. Also, why the downvotes? this is a perfectly valid question, and the original poster obviously needs help, so why vote down?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs thanks for the link but this tells abt basic ajax which i know, i need a aspecific answer for my problem... Can u help or is there anybody who can help, i am really stuck at this and the client is bugging me up for the solution..

Comment: "gonna take a while to understand" it really won't. Jquery AJAX is simples vs. Javascript AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('groups[]');  
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if (elements[i].checked){
        data.push('groups[]='+elements[i].value);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(data.join('&'));
//for get
//xmlhttp.open("GET",url+"?"+data.join('&'),true);
//xmlhttp.send();
```

EDIT

Change these two lines.

```
params = "tid="+tid+"&course="+a+"&sem="+b+"&paper="+c+"&"+data.join('&');

$groups = $_POST['groups'];
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the code.. i have a problem still as i am checking the values by alerting the variable data, according to ur code it is showing groups[]=1,groups[]=2 and so on... and when i changed the code to just output variable data, its shows 1,2,3 ... i just want to know how will i process the variable in php as suggested by u. i know if i coud get all the values in a php variable like $groups = $_POST[groups], i will run a foreach loop to make an insert for every value but how to go abt this using ur js code as it seems to me it will send multiple groups[] to php script..

Comment: It should work the same way , no need to change your php script

Comment: then in php script should i write $groups = $_POST['groups[]'] as what we are sending through javascript is groups[]=1&groups[]=2 and so on...

Comment: No just `$groups = $_POST['groups']` which will be an array

Comment: its not working either ways.. just to check, when i implode the php array its showing 2,3 as one array value and same with var_dump. somehow php taking all check box values as one array value. Please help..

Comment: @NikhilVerma Why are you imploding it, use it as you would if the form was submitted normally.

Comment: it is not working again... Its giving me the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".. Now i am in a fix.. As u said, i didn't change the php script at all and put in the js code provided by you but to no avail. Please suggest something, do u want me to post the js as well as php code..

Comment: hey i have edited question, posted the js including ur code and the php script.. please check

Comment: hey man, i changed it and it worked a like a charm.. you are the best :) .. One last thing although it is making the queries but its giving back fail and the js is going to the else code which says "there was a problem serving the request" and when i check the responsibilities are being created. Do u have any idea abt that?

Comment: @NikhilVerma you are echoing `done/fail` in a loop therefore it will output count($groups) `done/fail` not just one which you check for.

Comment: then can u suggest a way in order to get a confirmation that all the queries have been inserted or a fail flag if they fail somehow.

Comment: hey i am expanding this problem to include radio button values and sending them together with checkboxes as you suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756704/php-batch-processing-send-checkbox-and-radio-values-of-table-rows-together). Please, i need your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with two way,

1. you can use the post type ajax call
2. You can get the all selected checkbox values with JavaScript make comma separated string and just pass it in one variable

that's all you can do .... :)

Comment: comma separated, i did think but its too complex then in php to get the values and make an insert query for every value..