# PHP Batch Processing: send checkbox and radio values of table rows together

Tags: php, ajax, batch-processing

I am generating a table using the result of mysql query with checkboxes and radio buttons in each row like:

```
while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($q4))
 {
$pids = $row4['pid'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='pids[]' class='persistentChecks' style='display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;' value=".$pids."></td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;'>".$counter17."</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;'>".$row4['cname']."</td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;'>".$semester."</td>";
echo "<td style='font-size:12px;'><input type='radio' value='1'>Expert<input type='radio' value='2'>Normal";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;'>".$row4['pname']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$counter17 = $counter17 + 1;

 }
```

Its a batch processing problem. I want to send the values of the rows checked along with the radio button value of that checked row through ajax to a PHP page for insertion in MYSQL.

I know how to send only checked checkbox values with `push` and `join` functions of JS but am stuck on the way to send the associated radio button values of the checked rows along.

the JS i'm using is:

```
data = [];
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
 if (elements[i].checked){
        data.push('pids[]='+encodeURIComponent(elements[i].value));
      }
 }
 params= "teacher="+encodeURIComponent(teacher)+"&course="+encodeURIComponent(course)+"&semester="+encodeURIComponent(semester)+"&flag="+encodeURIComponent(1)+"&"+data.join('&');
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    result = xmlhttp.responseText;  
alert(result);

   }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","tpaper.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Now on the PHP page, i am looping through the pids sent through JS above using a foreach loop.

How am i supposed to send the radio button values of the checked checkboxes as well? Do i need to run a nested loop in JS and then in PHP `foreach` as well?

Please help...

Comment: You can do it in php only..

Answer (score 0):

Collect the radio values in another array at the same time as you collect the checkboxes.

```
data = [];
radio_data = [];
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if (elements[i].checked){
        var pid = elements[i].value;
        data.push('pids[]='+encodeURIComponent(pid));
        var radios_elements = document.getElementsByName('radio'+pid);
        for (var j = 0; j < radio_elements.length; j++) {
            if (radio_elements[j].checked) {
                radio_data.push('radios[]='+encodeURIComponent(radio_elements[j].value));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add them to the query string:

```
params= "teacher="+encodeURIComponent(teacher)+"&course="+encodeURIComponent(course)+"&semester="+encodeURIComponent(semester)+"&flag="+encodeURIComponent(1)+"&"+data.join('&')+&+radio_data.join('&');
```

Comment: this will only collect those radio values for whom the checkboxes have been checked? right? and then in PHP, am i supposed to run a single `foreach` loop or a nested one for radio buttons as well

Comment: Also, in the while loop, if i am giving the radio buttons the name as `radios[]`, it is being shared among all generated rows meaning i can click only one at a time.

Comment: Yes, since it only adds the radio values inside the `if(checked)` body, it will only send the ones associated with the checked boxes. A single loop in PHP should be able to get both of them.

Comment: When you use a name that ends in `[]`, PHP creates an array of all the values. So `$_GET['pids']` and `$_GET['radio']` will be arrays, and you can check as many as you want.

Comment: no no, i am saying that if i name the radio buttons as `radio[]` for all rows, it allows only one radio to be checked for all rows. how do i solve that?

Comment: i need your help on this last one

Comment: Oh, right. Change the names of the radio buttons to `radio$pid`.

Comment: and then i'll have to change the for loop in JS as well?

Comment: and you mean, name them as `radio$pid[]`?

Comment: i am not able to change the loop in JS as u suggested with the changed radio button names appended with pids

Comment: That will work, too. The `[]` in the name is irrelevant, since you're creating the query string with JS, not using the name from HTML.

Comment: Give them a class and use `getElementsByClassName` to create `radio_elements`.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if that will work right, since each checkbox of a radio is a separate element.

Comment: i am not following you on the class part. i wil be thankful, if you could explain some more. Please man, i see that you are much more experienced, i'm just a beginner, please help on this.

Comment: E.g. `<input class='radio' name='radio$pid' value='1'>Expert</input>`

Comment: Never mind that, see the new code I just added to the answer.

Comment: the new code is giving an Unexpected token error on the line radio_data.push('radios[]='+encodeURIComponent(radio_elements[i].value);

Comment: A missing close paren, I fixed

Comment: Aren't you using a code editor that warns about stuff like that? You should. Unfortunately, the SO editor doesn't.

Comment: sorry, everything is working fine except when im trying to alert the params being sent it is not attaching radio elements somehow

Comment: also, i don't understand but when i click on the submit button which runs JS function, its freezing my entire page. do u have any idea>/

Comment: i am noticing now, that the JS function alerts the params if only the first row is checked(without radio values still) but if any other row is checked it freezes the page. i'm pulling my hair over this.

Comment: You didn't post how you set `elements`, so I can't help you there.

Comment: `elements = document.getElementsByName('pids[]'); `

Comment: yes, i have been checking the console on every step and its nt giving any error in JS except when i submit the checked rows it freezes the entire page and i can't even open the console log then. i just have to close the page ultimately.

Comment: I'm talking about setting a breakpoint and then clicking on the single-step button to execute one line at a time, to see where it is when it hangs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30639/discussion-between-barmar-and-coder101)